# Hive on Spark return no results on aggregation or join queries

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

Aggregation or Join return no result from Hive Queries on external table.

I have setup hive to use Spark (stand alone) as query Engine instead of MR.

I have created an external table (from elastichsearch index).

With a SELECT all everithing is ok and data return:

`SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 100`

Try with a simple count no data return:

`SELECT count(*) FROM table1`

I use JDBC (beeline) to execute query on Hive

From the logs, it seems that the select query is executed directly on elastic (no spark job spawn). When count query is executed a spark job is spawn and complete successful but any result is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the join you are using is filtering out all the records. Check that the condition you are joining on exists in both tables. Try changing the join type from inner to left and see if you get any results.

If you still don't manage, can you please add a sample from the 2 tables you are trying to join?

Let me know.

Comment: I have found the problem. Spark write query results inside file system and tell to hive where read them. Hive and spark should share the location where those results are written (like HDFS)

Comment: Yes that is the configuration you have to set for both to work